# how do i get the id under another id in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

how do i get the id under another id in an if statement?

```
$('#mainmenu').mouseenter(function () {
  if ( $(this).???('#a')) {
        }  

  if ( $(this).???('#b')) {
        }  
});

<div id="mainmenu">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put the `mouseenter` even directly on the child divs instead trying to do if statements?  That way `$(this).attr("id")` will get you the ID of the element that the mouse is in?

Comment: What he said `$('#mainmenu div').mouseenter(...);` problem solved.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from your `if` statements? jQuery always returns an Object, which will always evaluate to `true`. Do you not mean `if ($(this).??('#a').size())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#mainmenu #a, #mainmenu #b').mouseenter(function(){
 // code for something cool...
});
```

HTH.

Comment: Would be easier to do `$("#a, #b", $("#mainmenu")).mouseenter(function(){ // ... });`

Comment: @RomanArmy, I prefer the CSS selector convention, each to his own poison I guess

Comment: This changes the intended behavior.
What if "#mainmenu" has something else inside, besides #a and #b?

Comment: From the example the OP has given I am under the impression that only 2 elements with defined ID's are to be selected...

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions, i'm sure they all work but i got my animatiions working with Sunny's code + if ( $(this).is('#a')) {
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `find` method.

`$(this).find('#a')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mainmenu').mouseenter(function () {

  if ($('#a', $(this)) {
    // your code here...............
  }  

  if ($('#b', $(this)) {
    // your code here...............
  }  

});
```

Comment: Technically the answer, but a weird way to get there.

Comment: I maybe don't understand something, but... How exactly is it supposed to work?

Comment: Ah! I see. Did you mean "$( '#a', $(this) )" ?

Comment: @Sarfraz: No, it doesn't. Look closer, you'll see. (I'm ruling out the possibility that you simply may not know Javascript...)

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: you picked up good point, i did not notice that, Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz: You're code will find the element with ID b, then check whether it's within $(this). Whilst my previous comment was probably a little harsh for the scenario in question, imagine the situation `$($('.someClass'), $(this));` where someone is attempting to speed up the selector. I'd prefer to use `$(raw-selector, filter)` throughout.

Comment: @Matt: agreed but i changed that even before your comment, thanks anyways.